# Postman - asserting where there are duplicate sections in JSON response

Tags: json, api, postman

This is my JSON response. I am wanting to write a test that asserts that cost = 1.000 where provider = Apple. As cost is repeated in the response, I'm struggling. How would I go about this? Thanks.

```
[
    {
        "provider": "Apple",
        "cost": 1.000,
        "active": true,
        "total": false
    },
    {
        "provider": "Banana",
        "cost": 0.000,
        "active": true,
        "total": false
    },
    {
        "provider": "Grape",
        "cost": 0.000,
        "active": true,
        "total": false
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write a test which loops through each object in the response, checks the `cost` value if the object contains the Apple value in the `provider` key:

```
let jsonData = pm.response.json()
pm.test('Check the price of the Apple', () => {
    _.each(jsonData, (item) => {
        if(item.provider === 'Apple') {
            pm.expect(item.cost).to.equal(1.000)
        } 
    })
})
```