# Postman test to parse json response body and validate there are no duplicate values in array

Tags: validation, duplicates, automated-tests, postman

I would like to write a test in Postman that validates there are no duplicate values in the array of objects. Here is an example response:

```
{
    "customerNumber": "123",
    "customCategories": [
        {
            "customCategoryID": "1546",
            "customCategoryDesc": "7100",
            "itemNumbers": [
                "7205",
                "1834"
            ]
        },
        {
            "customCategoryID": "1547",
            "customCategoryDesc": "7130",
            "itemNumbers": [
                "2251",
                "9832"
            ]
        },
        {
            "customCategoryID": "1548",
            "customCategoryDesc": "7315",
            "itemNumbers": [
                "1225541",
                "1197233"
            ]
        },
        {
            "customCategoryID": "1546",
            "customCategoryDesc": "7100",
            "itemNumbers": [
                "7205",
                "1834"
            ]
        },
    ]
}
```

As you can see, "customCategoryID": "1546" is repeated; thus I want a test to fail with this response, as well as display the repeated customCategoryID value ("1546").

I have viewed a couple of answers in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51025422/parse-json-postman-response) and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59846154/postman-asserting-where-there-are-duplicate-sections-in-json-response), but need to use the latest test script syntax for Postman has updated their JS library as well as have an assertion for the duplicated data.

Assistance with this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this to check for duplicate ids:

```
function checkIfArrayIsUnique(array) {
  return array.length === new Set(array).size;
}

pm.test('Check is Ids are unique', () => {
    let ids = []
    _.each(pm.response.json().customCategories, (item) => {
        ids.push(item.customCategoryID)
    })

    pm.expect(checkIfArrayIsUnique(ids), ids).to.be.true
})
```

It's looping through the `customCategoryID` property of each object in the `customCategories` array and storing that value in the `ids` array.

The `checkIfArrayIsUnique` function is taking that `ids` array and using the [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) method to help with the comparison.

The Set method creates a new object, from the `ids` array, that only contains unique values so it's checking to see if the `ids` array length matches the new Sets size, this returns either true or false.

There's a basic `pm.expect()` statement to check if the `checkIfArrayIsUnique` function returns true, if it's not unique it will return false and fail the test.

[image: Postman Test]

Comment: Ids list can be generated by map:  `let ids = pm.response.json().map(item => item.customCategories)`